# How to track windows server file folder and send notification if there are any new files added to folder

Tags: java, .net, shell, vbscript, windows-server-2008

we have production server environment there files will get received from other server if we got any new files need to send email notification to mapped users . how to do it any technology is fine I need solution for windows environment . 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a `WatchService` to generate file events on the specified directory:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html